# Problem with if/then statement and streamreader

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, streamreader

In my program I implemented proxy support.

I set up an if/then statement with a checkbox so basically it says if the checkbox is checked activate the proxy and use the proxies that the user uploaded into a list box.

I also have some streamreaders set up in my code which imports the text of a textfile in a text box. When I try to do proxies and try to import the text file it gives me some error saying the file could not be found but when I dont check the check box to use the proxy it imports it just fine.

This is the code for the checkbox:

```
if (chkBoxProxy.Checked)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex < listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
        listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
        RefreshIESettings(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown2.Value; i++)
        {
            listBox4.SetSelected(i, true);
            listBox4.SelectedItem.ToString();

           account();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown2.Value; i++)
    {
        listBox4.SetSelected(i, true);
        listBox4.SelectedItem.ToString();

        account();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for one of the several stream readers that I have:

```
StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader("website.txt");
string stream2 = stream1.ReadToEnd();
txtBoxImportWebsite.Text = stream2;

stream1.Close();
stream1.Dispose();
```

Comment: There are some problems in your code (`listBox4.SelectedItem.ToString()` doesn't do anything, you should use `using` to close the stream instead of calling `Dispose()` manually), but nothing that would cause the error you're describing. What line throws the exception? Does the file really exist? Can you post full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: When you say, "gives me some error", what do you mean?  That it throws an exception?  Have you looked at the callstack to validate which line of code is throwing that exception?  (And what are you passing in?)  Otherwise my psychic powers tell me that "website.txt" isn't in the current working directory (and you should use a full path to the file name) or some other line of code doing file io is throwing that exception.

Comment: listbox4.SelectedItem.ToString () basically gets the items in the listbox and uses it for the proxy. Its not a specific line that causes the error its all the stream readers if I check the proxy checkbox first. And the exact error is: FileNotFoundException was unhandled. I think I have a good hunch of whats causing the issue. When I check the proxy check box it looks in My Documents not in the programs folder, when I dont check it it looks in the programs folder. How do I fix this?

Comment: The first step of trying to fix this would be to get to know your code good enough to post samples that firstly describes the problem properly and secondly are connected somehow. I cannot tell where the "code for one of the several stream readers you have" is connected to the first code example at all. Also, theres no way to tell you how to fix the folder issue if we cant see how your File IO code looks like. Its like asking how much x * 243 equals to without giving us the value of x ...

Comment: I figured out that it was the first part of code that I put in my thread causing the problem.

Comment: How would I specify the path where the user installs the program to find the textfile?

Comment: Nevermind after searching on google all I had to do was: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\website.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boy your code is not complete enough, we should see exactly all the places where you call your stream management from. From where/what is the file `website.txt` created? why are you not specifying a full path when you open it?

as a general rule you should wrap your Streams with using so close and dispose is called automatically when using block ends and also in case of exceptions, you could rewrite your last fragment in this way:

```
using (var stream1 = new StreamReader("website.txt"))
{
  txtBoxImportWebsite.Text = stream1.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I didnt specify a full path because those textfiles are all contained where the software is installed. It works because I tested it. I will add the using statements, thanks. Maybe it will fix the problem.

Comment: the using alone won't eventually fix all your issues but as I said you should show more code.

Comment: Nope the issue still remains. Its strange because when I fill in one text box then go to the proxy and click the check box then go back the other imports work but when I check it first then try to import it doesnt work.

Comment: from where do you call StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader("website.txt"); ?

Comment: If I understood your question right I call it from a button. I set up individual buttons for each stream reader.

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader("password.txt");
            string stream2 = stream1.ReadToEnd();
            txtBoxImportPasswords.Text = stream2;





            stream1.Close();
            stream1.Dispose();
        }

Comment: The code I put was for the password another stream reader I had.